# Lost connectivity before receiving purchase receipt from apple In-app purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, receipt-validation

I have implemented In-app purchase in my app. So what I do is, after user completes payment with app store & the control goes to

`- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray<SKPaymentTransaction *> *)transactions`

then I update the purchase receipt to our server. Rest of the operations are done by server.

But one of our users faced an issue where he completed the payment but he lost internet connection before the above method was called. Resulting, our app does not know about the payment.

I know that the receipt is stored in the device. But is it the right way to send the receipt to the server from device every time user uses app??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, What i did to avoid this was, Keep a Check (like a boolean : `transactionInProgress`) when the transaction begin and when I have sent data to the server I change the value to "**NO**".

In this way the next time the app connects. just check if the `transactionInProgress` was checked, if it is then there was a transaction on going and you can fetch the receipt that must be stored by SKPaymentTransactions using

```
NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
if (!receipt) { /* No local receipt -- handle the error. */ }
```